# LateX names in Dagitty

Tags: r, latex, directed-acyclic-graphs

Does anyone know of a way to make variable labels in [Dagitty](http://www.dagitty.net/dags.html) with LateX (eg, I wanted to include subscripts and greek: eg $\lambda_1$).  I know that in plots for base R, there are ways to do this.

Here is a mininimal example

```
   library(dagitty)
    g = dagitty('dag{
  A [pos="-1,0.5"]
  W [pos="0.893,-0.422"]
  X [pos="0,-0.5"]
  Y [pos="1,0.5"]
  A -> Y
  X -> A
  X -> W
  X -> Y
}')
plot(g)
```

This gives a plot with A,B, etc as the labels.

Rather, I wanted something like $\alpha$ instead of A to be shown on the plot.

Comment: Show us how to create a simple plot of the kind you want in a self-contained reproducible example, and maybe we'll be able to tell you how to modify it to include LaTeX labels.  Without any code at all, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @user2554330 of course! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is kind of hard, because `dagitty` assumes the labels in the graph are plain text.  The branch of it available using

```
remotes::install_github("https://github.com/dmurdoch/dagitty", "nodelabels", "r")
```

will let you rename nodes using "plotmath" notation (see `?plotmath` in R).  For example,

```
   library(dagitty)
    g = dagitty('dag{
  A [pos="-1,0.5"]
  W [pos="0.893,-0.422"]
  X [pos="0,-0.5"]
  Y [pos="1,0.5"]
  A -> Y
  X -> A
  X -> W
  X -> Y
}')
plot(g, nodenames = expression(X = lambda[1]))
```

renames the X node to something like `$\lambda_1$`:

[image: screenshot]